# Why we need sequelize 'seed'?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js

What is seed concept in sequelize npm package.
I do not find this in any tutorial . I want to know why we need SEED.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Database seeding can be thought of as a way to bootstrap your database by inserting some records into it. This is run after the migrations created table structures for database.
Seeding could be generally split into 2 types:
- Dev/test/staging seeding: provide some initial dummy data to test data models or to demo features to customer.
- Production seeding: bootstrap your database with some essential data (mainly to provide some initial settings for your app)

Database seeding along with migration provide a way to package your app and its database as a whole to make it easier to deploy into any server.

Answer (score 1):

sequelize will assign a connection pool for connecting to the database. For example if you are connecting to the database by a single process then a process's instance will be created and will be alloted with full connection pool size but, if there are 4 processes connecting to the db and connection pool size is 160 then each process's instance will be assigned size of 40.

Seed is used to insert initial data to the database, like this:-

```
function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return [
      queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [
        { username: "user1" },
        { username: "user2" }
    ])];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly:
Seeders - files for filling the database with initial (dummy) data.

Detailed:

- Simply, these are started test data for rows in your table.
- You can clean and delete your database and if you need to create it again, add some started values FAST and SIMPLE - you just save commands for migrations and files of seeds.
- Then you can start to show, work with your database, test it, etc.